# How to use Internet Sharing on my Lumia 800

Tags: 7.8, nokia-lumia-800, internet-sharing, 3g

I upgraded my Nokia Lumia 800 to 7.8 using Zune. I forced it. I can see Internet Sharing in Settings but I can't turn it on. When I try to turn it on I get the error message "There is no cellular data connection right now. Check your cellular settings and signals right now and Try again.".

What should I do?

Comment: Have you checked your APN settings?

Answer (score 1):

Before turning on internet sharing, you should enable your cellular data connection

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/start/cellular-settings